# Problema con UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Estoy intentando actualizar un TextBox o Label a medida que un proceso avanza, para informar al usuario.

El código es el siguiente:

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="UpdatePanel.aspx.vb" Inherits="UpdatePanel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="ASPxButton">
    </dx:ASPxButton>
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="192px" 
                    Width="155px"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ASPxButton1"
                    EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Partial Class UpdatePanel
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub ASPxButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ASPxButton1.Click
    Proceso()
End Sub

Sub Proceso()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    TextBox1.Text = "Paso 1" & vbCrLf
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Paso 2" & vbCrLf
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Paso 3" & vbCrLf
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Paso 4" & vbCrLf
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Paso 5" & vbCrLf
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
End Sub
```

End Class

El problema es que el TextBox o Label sólo se actualiza cuando ha finalizado TODO el proceso, no paso a paso.

¿Qué es lo que hago mal?

He probado un móntón de variantes, pero no consigo dar con la respuesta.

Ayuda, por favor!!

Answer (score 0):

Es bastante decepcionante que NADIE responda a una pregunta.
Afortunadamente me he encontrado con una solución que no había encontrado en mis muchas búsquedas anteriores.

La solucion pasa por hacer dos páginas:
  1) El "frontend"
  2) El proceso

En el frontend se inserta un IFrame cuyo src es la página del proceso (genial!)

El código:

ASPX del frontend: (No hay Code Behind)

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Progress_IFrame.aspx.cs" Inherits="Progress_IFrame" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function BeginProcess() {
            // Create an iframe.
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

            // Point the iframe to the location of
            //  the long running process.
            iframe.src = "Progress_IFrame_Process.aspx";

            // Make the iframe invisible.
            iframe.style.display = "none";

            // Add the iframe to the DOM.  The process
            //  will begin execution at this point.
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);

            // Disable the button and blur it.
            document.getElementById('trigger').blur();
        }

        function UpdateProgress(PercentComplete, Message) {
            document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML + "<br />" + Message;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">                            
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <input type="submit" value="Start BackUp Process!" id="trigger" onclick="BeginProcess(); return false;" style="width: 250px;" />                        
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ProgressTemplate>                          
                    </ProgressTemplate> 
                </asp:UpdateProgress>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind del proceso (El ASPX es el de un WebForm que se genera por defecto)

```
    using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;

public partial class Progress_IFrame_Process : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        // Padding to circumvent IE's buffer.
        Response.Write(new string('*', 256));
        Response.Flush();

        // Initialization
        UpdateProgress(0, "Initializing task.");

        try
            {            
                UpdateProgress(10, " Paso 1....");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                UpdateProgress(33, " Paso 2....");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                UpdateProgress(66, " Paso 3....");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                SB.Append("<br/>");

            // All finished!
            UpdateProgress(100, "Proceso finalizado!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UpdateProgress(0, "Exception: " + ex.Message);

            SB.Append("Back Up Failed!");
            SB.Append("<br/>");
            SB.Append("Failed DataBase: ");
            SB.Append("<br/>");
            SB.Append("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected void UpdateProgress(double PercentComplete, string Message)
    {
        // Write out the parent script callback.
        Response.Write(String.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.UpdateProgress({0}, '{1}');</script>", PercentComplete, Message));
        // To be sure the response isn't buffered on the server.    
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Para que el ejemplo funcione tal cual está escrito, la página que contiene el proceso debe llamarse "Progress_IFrame_Process.aspx"